# http_build_query not giving me a valid URL when I send a form with GET method

Tags: php, forms, get

I have an Application and it uses GET parameters to render stuff... the URL for the product list looks like

```
appdomain.com/views/admin-panel.php?adminpage=product&task=list
```

I have this form:

```
            <form style="display: inline-block;" action="admin-panel.php?<?php echo http_build_query($_GET) ?>" method="get">
                <?php 
                $search = !empty($_GET["search"]) ? $_GET["search"] : "";
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $search; ?>"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
            </form>
```

When I send it, It should look like:

```
appdomain.com/views/admin-panel.php?adminpage=product&task=list&search=<USERINPUT>
```

But it actually looks like:

```
appdomain.com/views/admin-panel.php?search=<USERINPUT>
```

So... the app does not work because is lacking of the other parameters.

What am I doing wrong in the form action?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($_GET)` before you run `http_build_query`?

Comment: It prints: array (size=2)
  'adminpage' => string 'product' 
  'task' => string 'list' ... That's exactly what I want, to have these parameters when it sends the form, but with the search parameter added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make you form's method `post` to do this. Or stick with `get` and use hidden fields

```
<form action="foo.php?<?php echo http_build_query($bar) ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: Almost! I used GET and dinamically created hidden inputs with the current GET parameters

Comment: Yeah! Pretty much what i said!

Answer (score 0):

The trick to get a clean URL with the parameters you need, and without duplicates is this:

```
            <form style="display: inline-block;" action="admin-panel.php" method="get">
                <?php 
                foreach($_GET as $key=>$value) {
                    //Avoid duplicate parameters
                    if($key !== "search") {
                        ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"/>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                $search = !empty($_GET["search"]) ? $_GET["search"] : "";
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $search; ?>"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
            </form>
```